# Finding the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{z^{2}(1-z)}, 1<|z|<\infty $

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Finding the Laurent Series of

$\frac{1}{z^{2}(1-z)}, 1<|z|<\infty $

I tried to divide both numerator and denominator by $z^2$, so that there is a term of $\frac{1}{(1-z)}$.

I am tempted to use the formula for the sum of a geometric series, except the condition that |z|>1.

Is there an apparent way to resolve this, since there is no poles in the interval?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could use the formula for the sum of a geometric series if you had a term like $\frac{1}{1-1/z}$.

Comment: Ah I see. So divide the numerator and denominator again by z^2?

Comment: Right, just factor out $z$'s until it looks good. I'm not sure you have the total power to factor out correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u = \frac{1}{z}$.

Then 
$$f(u) = \frac{u^3}{u-1}$$
which, since $|u|< 1$ *can* be expanded as
$$
f(u) = -\sum_{n=3}^\infty u^n
$$
Then 
$$
f(z) = -z^{-3} - z^{-4} - z^{-5} \cdots
$$
which is the desired Laurent series.

Answer (score 0):

For $1<|z|<\infty$, we have $0<\left|\frac{1}{z}\right|<1$, and so
$$\frac{1}{{{z^2}\left( {1 - z} \right)}} = \frac{1}
{{{z^2}}}.\frac{1}
{{ - z\left( {1 - \frac{1}
{z}} \right)}} =  - \frac{1}
{{{z^3}}}\frac{1}
{{1 - \frac{1}
{z}}} =  - \frac{1}
{{{z^3}}}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{{\left( {\frac{1}
{z}} \right)}^n}}}
{{n!}}}  =  - \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{z^{ - \left( {n + 3} \right)}}}}
{{n!}}}$$

Comment: Whats with the factorial?